# Does $(n!)/n^{1000}$ diverge or converge

Tags: calculus

Wolfram alpha stated that this series converges to $0,$ but when I entered this answer in my homework it says it is incorrect, therefore I wanted to know whether this series diverges or converges.

Comment: Trust your teacher over Wolfram alpha.

Comment: Are you asking about a series or the sequence?

Comment: What? Why aren’t you applying any of the convergence tests that you were taught? having wolfram fill out your hw is an awful way to learn the material....

Comment: @lulu well, here, either would be false.

Comment: @ClementC.  Oh, of course, but I wanted to test WA.

Comment: Wolfram Alpha says the sum diverges. But it incorrectly says the sequence goes to zero. Weird. The only other thing it offers is a series expansion at infinity that clearly goes to infinity

Comment: James, the series $\sum_n^\infty \frac {n!}{n^{1000}}$ diverges.  You say that Wolfram sais this "series" converges, but I suspect you did not enter the series?

Comment: @JamesYuKaLong Yes it seems that WA doesn't work in this case! http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=lim+(n!%2Fn%5E100) Anyway note that since the sequence $a_n$ diverges (e.g. by ratio test) also the series $\sum a_n$ diverges

Comment: Oddly enough, mathematica (or open code, anyway) gets it right (or perhaps that's not so surprising)

Answer (score 3):

Note that by ratio test

$$\frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n}=\frac{(n+1)!}{(n+1)^{1000}}\frac{n^{1000}}{n!}=\frac{n+1}{\left(1+\frac1n\right)^{100}}\to \infty$$

then $a_n=\frac{n!}{n^{1000}}$ diverges.

Answer (score 2):

I diverges trivially: its general term
$$\frac{n!}{n^{1000}}\to +\infty$$
since $\;n^a=o(n!)$ for any $ a$.

Comment: It's a puzzle...WA agrees with you up to $\frac {n!}{n^{34}}$ but then it asserts that limit is $0$ for exponent $35$.  What on earth is it doing?

Comment: Maybe rounding errors. Mathematically, it well-known. Furthermore, it is well-known $n^a=o(\mathrm e^n)$ and $\mathrm e^n=o(n!)$. It follows by transitivity.

Answer (score 2):

A simple proof that
$n^a/n! \to 0$
for any $a > 0$:

By considering the last
$n/2$ terms in
$n!$,
each of which is
at least $n/2$,
we get
$n! > (n/2)^{n/2}
=(\sqrt{n/2})^n
$.

Therefore,
if $n > ka$,
$n^a/n!
\lt \dfrac{n^a}{(\sqrt{n/2})^n}
= (\dfrac{n^{a/n}}{\sqrt{n/2}})^n
\lt (\dfrac{n^{1/k}}{\sqrt{n/2}})^n
= (\dfrac{\sqrt{2}}{n^{1/2-1/k}})^n
\le (\dfrac{\sqrt{2}}{n^{1/4}})^n
$
if $k \ge 4$.

Therefore,
if
$n \ge 4a$,
$\dfrac{n^a}{n!}
\le (\dfrac{\sqrt{2}}{n^{1/4}})^n
$
and this clearly
goes to zero.

Answer (score 1):

Factorial always beats exponential, always beats polynomial, always beats logarithmic. Always.

So $x!/a^x, x→∞ = ∞$ for any $a$,
$a^x/x^b, x→∞ = ∞$ for any $a,b$,
$a^x/log_b(x), x→∞ = ∞$ for any $a$

You can verify with desmos! I tried $x!$ vs $18^x$, and $x!$ won at $x=5.6*10^{57}$

BTW, your thingy diverges